# Keyboard shortcuts for applying a theme

Tags: key-bindings, themes

I want to bind loading a specific theme to a key-binding.

However, this does not work.

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-<f1>") '(load-theme 'zenburn))
```

I would like Ctrl and the F1 key to apply the zenburn theme. But on executing the form I get

`Wrong type argument: commandp, (load-theme (quote zenburn))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-<f1>")
                (lambda () (interactive)
                  (load-theme 'zenburn t)))
```

The problem was that `global-set-key` expects a "command", meaning a function (defined, say, with `defun` or `lambda`) with the additional magic form `(interactive)` added after the arguments list, which tells Emacs that the function is meant to be invoked by the user. The `interactive` form takes optional arguments specifying, for example, whether your command should prompt for options in the minibuffer, and so forth.

Your`'(load-theme 'zenburn)` is not a command, or even a function; it's just arbitrary data (equivalent to the result of running `(list 'load-theme (list 'quote 'zenburn)`. Hence the error.

Note also that, since we trust zenburn, we're also applying `t` as the third argument to `load-theme`. Otherwise we'll be prompted to mark the theme as safe.

Comment: Oh nice, thanks! This works in Emacs' gui mode, but not in the terminal mode (i..e when using emacs -nw) What should I add to the code?

Comment: It works in my terminal (Konsole). My guess is that your terminal is intercepting the C-<f1> event, preventing Emacs from seeing it. Hopefully your terminal provides an option to disable this behavior. Otherwise, you'll probably have to pick a different key sequence.

Comment: Oh great! Indeed there was a binding, but I looked at konsole and I like it better than my current terminal emulator. :-D will be switching to it!